# How to change root cert in a running Hyperledger fabric network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

For example the orderer root cert is to be expired in a week, is there any method to replace or expand the root cert without reset the whole network?
I know the root cert is included in the MSP part as config in the genesis.block, is that possible to modify or update genesis.block?

Answer (score 0):

These documentation pages might help:

- https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/raft_configuration.html#tls-certificate-rotation-for-an-orderer-node
- https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/configtx.html#configuration-updates
- https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/config_update.html